# Javascript Prototype: Get siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

I'm new to the prototype thing. I'm making an accordion and I want all the siblings to close once the current clicked accordion item opens. This is my code:

```
function accordionItem(node) {
  this.node = node;
  this.opened = false;
  this.siblings = $(this.node).siblings();
  this.btn = $(this.node).find('[data-accordion-item-btn]');
  this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  $(this.btn).on('click', this.toggle);
}

accordionItem.prototype.toggle = function() {
  if (this.opened) {
    this.close();
  } else {
    this.open();
    this.siblings.close();
  }
};

accordionItem.prototype.close = function() {
  this.opened = false;
  this.btn.attr('aria-expanded', 'false');
};

accordionItem.prototype.open = function() {
  this.opened = true;
  this.btn.attr('aria-expanded', 'true');
};

$('[data-accordion-item]').each(function() {
  new accordionItem(this);
});
```

this.siblings.close(); obviously doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: A working example would be great to understand the problem

Comment: The `.siblings` are are jQuery collection, not an `accordionItem` instance, they have no `.close()` method.